# React Performance: Why immutable data could imporve react performance?

Tags: performance, reactjs

I just read React official [Optimizing Performance](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/optimizing-performance.html) guide. One advide of the article is to use immutable data and how to use them.

But it doesn't tell why immutable data could imporve the preformance. And I want to know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you provided explains:

> Immutability makes tracking changes cheap. A change will always result
>   in a new object so we only need to check if the reference to the
>   object has changed.

Instead of checking each property of an object, and then those properties' properties, etc., it just needs to see if the top-level reference has changed.

Comment: Sorry, my bad :p

Answer (score 0):

The immutability plays a roles while comparing the previous state with the current state in **shouldComponentUpdate function**

**for example:**

1. we have some flight data coming from the backend
2. After some operations you need to update the data, and you need to change the price.

**Previous state**

flight = {
name: 'air india', 
price: 5000
}

**updated data from the backend**

price is change to 6000

**There are two ways to do the change**

1. one directly changing(mutating) the object

> flight.price = 6000

2. Creating a new copy and doing those changes to that copy.

> ```
> let modifyFlight = [...flight]; 
> modifyFlight.price = 6000;
> and set the state
> ```

---

what is the difference between the above two approaches?
Before we go into deep we need to understand how **ShouldComponentUpdate** works.

```
function   shouldComponentUpdate (nextProps, nextState) {
  return  nextProps.flight !==  this .props.flight;
 }
```

In the above function which takes a call to continue the **updation lifecycle** or not it will check only the reference, with the first approach **there won't be any change in the reference** so this function returns false and **stops the updation life cycle**,

But when we create a new object and do the required changes **the reference address in the memory changes and doesn't match with previous object address**, so ShouldComponentUpdate will return true and updation life cycle triggers.

As a final Note, we can use Immutability.js or any other js library to stop mutation of objets which halts the unnecessary  rendering.